# Min/max, inf/sup

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Determine if the sets:

(a){x ∈ Q} ∩ {${1 \over \sqrt{n}}$ : n ∈ N}

(b) {x ∈ R : $x^2 −2>0$ }

Have a minimum, a maximum, an infimum, and a supremum.

For a: If n = 1, ${1 \over \sqrt{n}} = 1 $  and it's a maximum, 1 is also a supremum.

There is't minimus, because if n increases the set decreases but never becomes  less then 0 because s is positive. So min = no, infimum = 0.

For b: $x^2 > 2$ and $x > + \sqrt{2}$  and  $ x < - \sqrt{2}$

There isn't min or max, infimum is $ - \infty $ and supremum is $ + \infty $

Is it correct and full explanation?

Comment: why not $x > \sqrt {2}$ and $x< \sqrt {-2}$ ?

Comment: @Afzal - $|x| > \sqrt 2$ means $-\sqrt 2 < x < \sqrt 2$ would be **false**. It should not be included in your list.

Comment: @Idon'tneedaname - the correct inequality for (b) is "$x > \sqrt 2$ **or** $x < -\sqrt 2$" There is no value $x$ can take on that is both $> \sqrt 2$ **and** $< -\sqrt 2$. Math requires precision in terminology. Don't misuse it.